# Distinguish contraction of "ain't"

Tags: meaning, slang, ambiguity, contractions, aint

I know the contraction of  *am not*, *is not*, *are not*, *has not*, *have not*, *do not*, *does not*, and *did not*  can be represented as *ain't*. How can I understand correctly which contraction the speaker meant?

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you think confusion may arise?

Comment: @BarrieEngland:For an instance,"I ain't do anything".In that sentence, we can mean as it may be "i am not do anything" or "i do not do anything" or "i did not do anything" and so on.

Comment: If you mean 'I ain't doing anything', it would mean 'I am not doing anything' because that would be the normal thing to say. If  the speaker wanted to express either of the other two it would be necessary to say them in full. The context will almost always show what it is intended.

Comment: You would never hear "I ain't do anything". Possibly "I ain't done anything" or "I ain't doing anything". Similarly, "I am not do anything" sounds ungrammatical. Better would be "I am not doing anything" or "I did not do anything".

Comment: @ConcreteGannet,&Barrie England,Yes i was wrong.It was "I ain't done anything".But many times i get confused and i ain't remember the sentences!!

Comment: 'I ain't do anything' is actually heard in some varieties of southeren American and [African-American Vernacular English](http://books.google.com/books?id=FSDFt4a__YEC&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=%22ain't+do%22+AAVE&source=bl&ots=QFsvgPy6p6&sig=pyZ1vBxXkw3ANZ0MoXWnA7Zdze0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4dQqT_CHNcunsAKx_NDFDg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22ain't%20do%22%20AAVE&f=false).

Comment: @MarkBeadles If so,what is the exact meaning of that?

Comment: It's equivalent to "I didn't do anything".

Comment: Regarding "I ain't do anything" -- I most certainly have heard that. It means I did not do anything and is used chiefly in non-standard American English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context. "am", "is" and "are" are all parts of the verb "to be", so the subject of the verb will tell you what is meant.

I ain't ready - I am not ready
You ain't ready - You are not ready

I ain't got a clue - I haven't got a clue. The got hints we are talking about having or possession.

I think using ain't as a negation of "to do" is much rarer, and if you are in doubt, it's unlikely to be the right answer.

Comment: **"subject of the verb will tell you what is meant"**,Very Simple!!